# Regex using recursion with groups

Tags: regex, pcre2

I am not certain if there's any regex magic that can do this:

```
foo(f1, f2()) = bar { b1, b2 {}} //match all of this
foo(f3) // dont match this
bar{b3} // dont match this
```

what I am trying to do is capture an entire line if it contains this pattern:

> ```
> \w+\((?:[^()]|(?RECURSION ON PARENTHESES))*\)\s*=\s*\w+{(?:[^{}]|(?RECURSION ON CURLY BRACKETS))*}
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [regex subroutines](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html):

```
\w+\s*(\((?:[^()]++|(?-1))*\))\s*=\s*\w+\s*({(?:[^{}]++|(?-1))*})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d9QEqT/1).

*Details*:

- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\((?:[^()]++|(?-1))*\))` - a substring between paired nested parentheses
- `\s*=\s*` - a `=` char enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `\w+\s*` - one or more word chars, zero or more whitespaces
- `({(?:[^{}]++|(?-1))*})` - a substring between paired nested curly braces.

Note the `(?-1)` recurses the latest capturing group pattern.